# Is there a way to disable JSDoc generation in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

It looks like V1.10 added auto JSDoc generation when typing `/**`.

Is there a ways to disable this functionality so it just generates a normal comment block and does not add the parsed params?

Comment: what is CS code?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal Given the tags, it appears OP mean [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Comment: I originally meant VS code. The community has corrected my errors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't disable this in the current release but the next update (April) will have a new [option in settings](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23642) - `jsDocCompletion.enabled`.

Right now, because this feature is using template expansion, you can just hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> after typing `/**` when the autocomplete hint appears and before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: I still can't disable this, at the end of 2021, even after disabling the settings. It still completes the comments, and I hate it. Note that it doesn't pop up the menu, it just adds the characters. WHYYY?

Answer (score 0):

## Update for VSCode 2021 (v1.54) and up

`jsDocCompletion.enabled` was deprecated for the [February 2021](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_54) release with the inclusion of Typescript 4.2 into VSCode as standard.

It was superceded by `[configuration].suggest.completeJSDocs` and some accompanying settings were also included to allow more granular control over how Javascript and Typescript are handled.

The JSDoc related settings for each language are:

- `suggest.completeJSDocs` [ true | false ]
- `suggest.jsdoc.generateReturns` [ true | false ]

With these settings you are able to [choose whether or not to generate `@return` tags](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_54#_js-doc-templates-now-generate-returns) and/or disable JSDocs completely on a per-language basis.

#### In the settings editor

From the application menu, navigate to

- `File > Preferences > Settings` on Windows/Linux (default shortcut `Ctrl+,`)
- `Code > Preferences > Settings` on macOS (default shortcut `⌘,`)

Type `JSDocs` in the search bar at the top or select `Extensions > Typescript` from the submenu on the left.

**Note:** You can also open the Settings editor from the Command Palette

#### In settings.json

```js
{
  /* Values are defaulted to true but do not appear in the
     user's default settings.json file */

  "javascript.suggest.completeJSDocs": true,
  "javascript.suggest.jsdoc.generateReturns": true,
  "typescript.suggest.completeJSDocs": true,
  "typescript.suggest.jsdoc.generateReturns": true
}
```